# is there anyway to create animation within sfml using a rectangle

Tags: c++, algorithm, animation, sfml

Is there any way to create a animation in sfml. not with spritesheets. but with 1 rectangle going to another position.
https://gyazo.com/0952a960bd7f9e5c9c5e1fe71d0f0b45
I want a punching effect similar to that. but I don't where to begin with.

Is there anyway to make a smooth animation within sfml?

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way would be with sprite sheets, but it can be done without.
Make a for loop that moves the position of the rectangle and than returns it back

```
float smoothness //try for your values
float directionX; //if negative punch left set values 1 or -1
float directionY; //if negative punch down set values 1 or -1
int reach;
for(int i=0;i<reach;i++)
{
     rect.setPosition(
     directionX*(rect.getPosition.x+smoothness)
     ,directionY*(rect.getPosition.y+smoothness))
}
//return to original position
for(int i=0;i<reach;i++)
{
     rect.setPosition(
     -directionX*(rect.getPosition.x+smoothness)
     ,-directionY*(rect.getPosition.y+smoothness))
}
```

**NOTE:**
 Please set a constant framerate for this to work properly

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the rectangle to get such effect. You probably want to scale its length more than its width to get it similar to the example you posted.

To animate that scale, scale it a little bit at a time (once per update/timestep or tick/frame/loop) until it reaches the larger scale and then return its scale back to its original size.

Instead of scaling, you could set the size directly instead.

You could also interpolate between the two sizes or scales based on start and end times.